# COUNTA for ongoing range Excel

Tags: excel, count

If I have a table in Excel like so:

```
        A
1
2    | Name |
3   --------
4     Todd
5     Chris
6     Joe
7     Alex
```

Now I know how to count all the rows that have data in them like so:

```
=COUNTA(A4:A7) // which should equal 4
```

Now I believe I have done this in the past, but I am having trouble remembering how to do it...

How do I extend the range to be infinite, and not static on `A7`?

For example, if I wanted to add `Bob` into `A8`, how do I get the `COUNTA` to extend to `A8`, and so on and so on (depending on how many values I enter under `A`), without having to manually change the range values each time I add something into the list?

I need the range to start at cell `A4`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @hstay If I use that formula, it will add in the top 3 lines as well... the ------, along with the | Name |, and the blank A1 cell.. so my count will be off by 3.. the range needs to start at A4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider:

```
=COUNTA(A:A)-COUNTA(A1:A3)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
=COUNTA(A:A)
```

This should do the trick for the full column.

If you would like to start from A4 and move infinitely from there, use:

```
=COUNTA(A4:A1048576)
```

Comment: If I use that formula, it will add in the top 3 lines as well... the `------`, along with the `| Name |`, and the blank `A1` cell.. so my count will be off by 3.. the range needs to start at `A4`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dynamic named range. Go to Formulas>Name Manager>New then name is Names (or whatever you want) and make this for your formula `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$4,,,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A$4:$A$400),1)` .

Then just simply use `=COUNTA(Names)`

Hope this helps, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you use Excel Table (Insert tab and Table) in Excel 2007 or above you can use [structured reference](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-structured-references-with-Excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e)

```
= CountA( Table1[Name] )
```